# how to convert filesystem path to string

Tags: c++, c++17

I am iterating through all the files in a folder and just want their names in a string. I want to get a string from a [`std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path). How do I do that?

My code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

int main()
{
    std::string path = "C:/Users/user1/Desktop";
    for (auto & p : fs::directory_iterator(path))
        std::string fileName = p.path;
}
```

However I get the following error:

```
non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to a member.
```

Comment: `p.path` is a member *function*, you cannot use it without `()`. Try `std::string fileName = p.path();`

Comment: ya plus a .string() at the end so: std::string fName = p.path().string();

Answer (score 98, accepted):

To convert a [`std::filesystem::path`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) to a natively-encoded string (whose type is `std::filesystem::path::value_type`), use the [`string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/string) method. Note the other `*string()` methods, which enable you to obtain strings of a specific encoding (e.g. `u8string()` for an UTF-8 string).

C++17 example:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    fs::path path{fs::u8path(u8"愛.txt")};
    std::string path_string{path.u8string()};
}
```

C++20 example (better language and library UTF-8 support):

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    fs::path path{u8"愛.txt"};
    std::u8string path_string{path.u8string()};
}
```

Comment: if   #include  <filesystem> and namespace fs = std::filesystem; doesn't work try this one:  #include <experimental/filesystem>
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

Comment: @jstar that's because your standard library is out of date -- time to upgrade :)

Comment: (FYI for newbies like me) `*string()` means, there are `string()`, `wstring()`, `u8string()`, `u16string()`, `u32string()` if you have a look at the source code.

Answer (score 12):

In C++ 17 and above, you can use .generic_string() to convert the path to a string: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/generic_string.

The following is an example that gets the current working directory and converts it into a string.

```
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>
using std::filesystem::current_path;

int main()
{
    filesystem::path directoryPath = current_path();
    string stringpath = directoryPath.generic_string();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The examples given in the accepted answer, using the UTF-8 operations, are fine and a good guideline. There is just one error in the introductory explanation given in the answer, which Windows/MSVC developers should be aware of:

The [`string()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/string) method does **not** return the natively-encoded string (which would be `std::wstring()` on Windows), but rather it always returns a `std::string`. It also tries to convert the path to the local encoding, which is not always possible, if the path contains a unicode character not representable in the current code page and then the method **throws an exception**!

If you actually want the behavior that is described in the answer (method returns native string, i.e., `std::string` on Linux and `std::wstring` on Windows), you would have to use the [`native()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/native) method or the implicit conversion based on [`std::filesystem::path::operator string_type()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/native), but as @tambre correctly pointed out in the examples, you should consider using the UTF-8 versions throughout.

Comment: could you show an example that throws on Windows? The cppreference docs don't indicate what happens with the string method there.

Comment: Nevermind, just managed to reproduce it myself. The exception's `what()` text explicitly says `No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page`. I wonder if this is documented anywhere, since at least cppreference doesn't say anything.