# How can I convert an std::filesystem::path to LPCSTR for use in one of the LoadLibrary() variants?

Tags: c++, windows, loadlibrary, std-filesystem

On Windows I'm trying to use one of the variants of `LoadLibrary()` to open a `dll` previously written to an `std::filesystem::path` with an `ofstream`.

Note: I know the dll is written correctly as I can use it in the standard fashion by linking to it at runtime.

I've been trying to combine the methods from the two answers below.

[How to convert std::string to LPCSTR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200188/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lpcstr)

[how to convert filesystem path to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45401822/how-to-convert-filesystem-path-to-string)

This seems like it should be pretty basic but with anything I've tried so far I either get an error about conversion to LPCSTR or something like `C2228: left of '.c_str' must have class/struct/union` which I am baffled by.

Here's a simple example:

```
// Assuming I have 
// std::filesystem::path path1 
// correctly set, I should be able to directly access it in
// a number of ways; i.e. path1.c_str(), path1.string.c_str(), etc.
// in order to pass it the function or a temp variable.
// However direct use of it in LoadLibrary() fails with the C2228 error.

HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary(path1.c_str());
```

I've tried avoiding the macro and calling `LoadLibraryA()` directly with no luck.
I've also tried various ways of passing `path1` with `path1.string()`, `path1.string.c_str()`, path1.wstring(), etc. with no luck.
I've also tried using a temp variable in a number of ways to avoid the cast within `LoadLibrary()`.

```
LPCSTR temp_lpcstr = path1.c_str();  // Also tried things like path1.string() path1.string.c_str()

// Also tried just using a temp string...
std::string temp_string = path1.string(); // and variants.
```

I'm willing to try playing with the encoding (like `path1.u8string()` etc.) but I think it shouldn't be necessary with use of `LoadLibraryA()` directly.

I'm trying to avoid C casts and would prefer a c++ static_ or dynamic_ but I'll use anything that works.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

`UPDATE`

@eryk-sun's comment and @Gulrak's answer solved it for me.
It looks like with my setup, `path1.c_str()` alone is `wchar_t` but the LoadLibrary() macro was not picking that up and directing it to LoadLibraryW() as it should.

Note: For anyone else who might stumble onto this in the future here's more details of my specific setup.  I'm using the MSVC compiler from 16.1.0 (~VS2019) but that's getting called from VSCode and CMake.  I'm not explicitly defining _UNICODE however VSCode's intellisense certainly thinks it's been defined somewhere and points me to LoadLibraryA().  However, I think the compiler is not actually seeing that define so it interprets `path1.c_str()` as a `wchar_t`.

Comment: Are you using MSVC (Visual Studio)? Which version of it? `std::filesystem` is rather new, and MSVC often lags a little in its standard compliance.

Comment: `LoadLibrary(path.c_str());` works in MSVC 2019.

Comment: `C2228: left of '.c_str' must have class/struct/union` means that you're calling `.c_str()` on an object for which the compiler does not know the type. (It doesn't understand what `path1` is and therefore doesn't think that member access is legal.) Your problem has nothing to do with `LoadLibrary`/`LoadLibraryA`, encoding, casts, etc.

Comment: If you want more help, then please give us more information (like the compiler version), and please show us a [mcve] together with a full and complete copy-paste (as text) of the error messages. Also please take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: In Windows, [`filesystem::path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/path-class?view=vs-2019) uses `wchar_t` strings. This has nothing to do with the WINAPI `UNICODE` macro  (not `_UNICODE`, which is for the CRT).  So `c_str()` is a wide-character C string, and you have to call `string().c_str()` to get a byte string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually on Windows you should be able to use `LoadLibraryW(path1.c_str())` as on Windows the returned type of std::filesystem::path::c_str() should be a `const wchar_t*` so it's a good fit for the `LoadLibraryW` expected `LPCWSTR`.

As for the error of `C2228` my guess is, you tried `path1.string.c_str()` as given by your comment, wich should have been `path1.string().c_str()`. That would give you a `LPCSTR` compatible string for `LoadLibaryA`, but if there is a chance of Non-ASCII in your path I would suggest using the explicit `LoadLibaryW` version.

In any way: When interfacing WinAPI with `std::filesystem::path` you should use the explicit A/W-Version to make your code safe independent of the state of `_UNICODE`, and I allways suggest the `*W` versions.

Comment: That was it.  Thanks, @Gulrak.

Comment: Since `LoadLibraryW` is Windows, then it's okay to use `c_str()` directly and assume it's `wchar_t *`, but I think it's clearer to use `path1.wstring().c_str()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `string` member function of `path` class which returns `std::string`. Then call `c_str`on the returned string.
`std::filesystem::path path /* = initialization here */;
std::string str = path.string();
/* some handle = */ LoadLibrary(str.c_str());`

Comment: I assume `path.string()` encodes the path string using the system-locale ANSI encoding,  but a path can include Unicode characters that aren't mapped in that codepage (e.g. user profile directories quite often contain character's that can't be encoded as system ANSI). It would be safer in Windows to use `path.wstring()` with `LoadLibraryW`, which uses the native `wchar_t` string type of the Windows platform.

Comment: @navyblue: I definitely tried using an extra std::string just as you mentioned but that too gave me the C2228 error.

It looks like @eryk-sun and @Gulrak have nailed it.  In my case I need to call `LoadLibraryW(path1.c_str())` instead of LoadLibrary() or LoadLibraryA().

Comment: @Morgan, `path1.wstring().c_str()` does work to get a `wchar_t *` string that `LoadLibraryW` expects. I tested this with VC++. The explicit `wstring()` call ensures it's the right string type, though in Windows (not Unix) `path1.c_str()` on its own will be a `wchar_t *` string.

Comment: @morgan, I also checked that `path1.string().c_str()` returns an encoded `char *` string, and stepped through to confirm that it's encoded via `WideCharToMultiByte` with `CP_ACP` (i.e. system ANSI), so it's the right encoding for `LoadLibraryA`. However, I advise against using `LoadLibraryA` -- and the Windows multibyte string (ANSI) API in general -- until it's commonly UTF-8. Currently it's still commonly a non-Unicode legacy encoding, such as codepage 1252. Avoid legacy encodings.